# Obtaining a List from Parse without auto-selecting when obtained in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, list, parse-platform, spinner

The title says it all, I'm trying to do that because I obtain a list from parse and the user must choose one of them from a spinner and based on the user's choice it responds and sets another filter to another spinner. The problem I'm having (really not much of a deal, but it's something that I'd like to do) is that when the list gets obtained from Parse it automatically selects the first one it retrieves and fills all the spinners automatically (of course you can change it and it will work perfectly).

The question is, how do I retrieve a list from parse, add it into a spinner in a way that it doesn't fill everything by itself ?

Here's my piece of code where I obtain the list and add it into a spinner:

```
groupSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("Group Item Selected Ran");
            final String spinI1 = groupSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Hospitales");
            query.whereEqualTo("grupo", spinI1);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
                    int size = 0;
                    size = parseObjects.size();
                    String[] mod = new String[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < parseObjects.size(); i++) {
                        mod[i] = parseObjects.get(i).getString("Hospital");
                        System.out.println(mod[i]);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HandsetLocation.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mod);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                    hospitalSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: How about adding a default value at index 0, say,  "select value" or something. Then you can ignore that string in the rest of your code, knowing that nothing has been actively selected.

Comment: I tried doing that but I couldn't achieve it always crashed because of an invalid length :( how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my phone so cannot properly indent the code but here it goes:

```
                String[] mod = new String[size+1];
                mod[0] = "select value";
                for (int i = 0; i < parseObjects.size(); i++) {
                    mod[i+1] = parseObjects.get(i).getString("Hospital");
                    System.out.println(mod[i+1]);
                }
```

Comment: I added it and it crashes the app plus it skips the first item on the list :( I put a System output and it gave me all the items retrieved but it skipped the first one

Comment: You need to start the loop at zero instead of one, and then add to the array at position `i + 1`.  I edited the answer but it hasn't been reviewed yet.

Comment: Added. Still crashes. I'm really clueless about what the problem may be.

Comment: Oh sorry, went to sleep right after .. yeah of course my bad, code should be corrected in a second

Comment: Still crashes with the new edit :(. Solved it! I guess you just missed to add it, but I added i+1 in mod[i]

Comment: Thanks a lot. mod[i] = parseObjects.get(i).getString("Hospital"); in that line I added a +1 after the first mod[i]

Comment: No problem. Yes had only added it in the output, is added now :-)